# SSRS Can we set a break page between each instances of the 2nd row group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm new to SSRS...
I have a tablix report and would like to set a break page between each instance of the second row group of my report.

Here are the row groups :

```
 -EmployeeFullName
 -CalendarYear
 -CalendarSemester
 -CalendarQuarter
 -Month
```

I need a new page to be created for each `CalendarYear`.
Is it possible or should `CalendarYear` be the first row group?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can insert a page break based upon each new instance of the second row group.

right mouse click CalenderYear row group, go to group properties, go to Page Breaks, select tick in Between each instance of a group, click OK.